# Collsion Detection Sprite-Kit Bitmasking

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision-detection

Ive spent weeks trying to fully grasp collision detection in Sprite-Kit using BitMasking. Ive Searched google youtube and cant find anything. Ill post the code I have now. The code I have now is not currently working when my two SKSpriteNodes Come in contact with each other. Can someone show me how to fix my code AND show me the steps and what they mean.

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate{

let ballCategory:UInt32 = 0x1 << 0
let boxCategory:UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
let ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "redball")
let redBall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "redball")


override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    let box = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "box")
    box.position = CGPoint(x: 400, y: 400)
    box.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = boxCategory
    box.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = boxCategory
    box.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = boxCategory | ballCategory
    addChild(box)

    redBall.position = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200)
    redBall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ballCategory
    redBall.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ballCategory
    redBall.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ballCategory | boxCategory
    addChild(redBall)

    //Backround Properties
    backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 70.0/255.0, green: 67.0/255.0, blue: 67.0/255, alpha: 1)

}




override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let touch = touches.first as! UITouch
    let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
    redBall.position = touchLocation

}
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let touch = touches.first as! UITouch
    let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
    redBall.position = touchLocation
}
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let contactBodyA = SKSpriteNode()
    let contactBodyB = SKSpriteNode()

    if(contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ballCategory) && (contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == boxCategory){

        println("contact was made")
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The problem is you never made physics bodies. All those assignments you make on the physics bodies never happen because they're nil by default

Answer (score 0):

I have modify some of your code and now it is working fine. And here is your code:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate{

    let ballCategory:UInt32 = 0x1 << 0
    let boxCategory:UInt32 = 0x1 << 1

    let ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "redball")
    let redBall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "redball")


    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
        //make gravity 0
        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0, 0.0)

        let box = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "redball")
        box.position = CGPoint(x: 400, y: 400)
        //add physicsbody for collisin detection
        box.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "redball"), size: box.size)
        //assign a correct cetogary
        box.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = boxCategory
        box.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask =  ballCategory
        box.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask =  ballCategory
        addChild(box)

        redBall.position = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200)
        //add physics body
        redBall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "redball"), size: redBall.size)
        //assign correct cetogary
        redBall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ballCategory
        redBall.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = boxCategory
        redBall.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = boxCategory
        addChild(redBall)

        //Backround Properties
        backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 70.0/255.0, green: 67.0/255.0, blue: 67.0/255, alpha: 1)

    }




    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first! 
        let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
        redBall.position = touchLocation
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first!
        let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
        redBall.position = touchLocation
    }

    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        // 1. Create local variables for two physics bodies
        var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
        var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody

        // 2. Assign the two physics bodies so that the one with the lower category is always stored in firstBody
        if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
            firstBody = contact.bodyA
            secondBody = contact.bodyB
        } else {
            firstBody = contact.bodyB
            secondBody = contact.bodyA
        }

        // 3. react to the contact between ball and bottom
        if firstBody.categoryBitMask == ballCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == boxCategory {
            //TODO: Replace the log statement with display of Game Over Scene
            //add your code here.
            print("Called")
        }
    }
}
```

Tested with xCode 7.

[HERE](http://www.raywenderlich.com/84434/sprite-kit-swift-tutorial-beginners) is great tutorial about spriteKit where you can learn more.